# How to select joined rows even if there is no match?

Tags: sql, join, firebird

I checked so many similar questions but none apply to Firebird I guess.

I have two tables; one stores the customer information and the second stores the stock activities (which also includes orders). I'd like to fetch all customers and the counts of orders they have made. But no matter how I join the orders table; I end up with only the customers that have at least one order. That means customers who don't have a match in the stock activities table won't show up in the result set.

Here is the query I run;

```
SELECT
  C.NAME, C.GROUPNAME, C.EMAIL,
  COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT S.ORDERNO), '0') AS TOTALORDERS,
  COALESCE(SUM(S.AMOUNT), '0') as TOTALREVENUE
FROM CUSTOMERS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_ACTIVITY S ON C.ID = S.CUSTOMERID
WHERE C.GROUPNAME = 'B'
  AND (S.TYPE = 'RECEIPT' OR S.TYPE = 'INVOICE')
GROUP BY C.NAME, C.GROUPNAME, C.EMAIL
```

Without the join, I get 570 rows (of customers) and it's the correct result set. When I join the orders table to fetch the total order amount of these customers; I get only 379 results; which are the ones having at least one order. That means customers who don't have orders won't return. As you might have guessed; I want to have the customers having zero activity to return "0" as order amount and revenue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `WHERE` clause filters on the "right hand" table's values.

```
WHERE ...
  AND (S.TYPE = 'RECEIPT' OR S.TYPE = 'INVOICE')
```

When the outer join generates records for "unmatched" rows from the left table, it supplies `NULL` values for all columns from the right table.  So `S.TYPE` is `NULL` for those records.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Explicitly allow for the "`NULL` record" case in your `WHERE` logic.

By some standards this might be "more pure" in separating join conditions from filters, but it can get fairly complicated (and hence error-prone).  One issue to be aware of is that you may have to distinguish generated `NULL` records from "real" records of the right table that just happen to have some `NULL` data.

Testing for the right table's value for the join key to be `NULL` should be reasonably safe.  You could test for the right table's PK value to be `NULL` (assuming you have a true PK on that table).

2. Move the predicate from the `WHERE` clause to the outer join's `ON` clause.

This is very simple, and looks like

```
SELECT C.NAME, C.GROUPNAME, C.EMAIL,
       COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT S.ORDERNO), '0') AS TOTALORDERS,
       COALESCE(SUM(S.AMOUNT), '0') as TOTALREVENUE
  FROM                 CUSTOMERS C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN STOCK_ACTIVITY S
                    ON C.ID = S.CUSTOMERID
                   AND (S.TYPE = 'RECEIPT' OR S.TYPE = 'INVOICE')
 WHERE C.GROUPNAME = 'B'
 GROUP BY C.NAME, C.GROUPNAME, C.EMAIL
```

This effectively filters the `STOCK_ACTIVITY` records presented to the join before attempting to match them against `CUSTOMERS` records (meaning the `NULL` records can still be generated without interference).  ("Effectively" because it's folly to talk like you know what steps the DBMS will follow; all we can say is this has the same effect that you'd get by following certain steps...)

Comment: Thanks; this has done the work. While the two different options produced different results. Interestingly, having the filter attached into the join produced 2 lines less than the where clause.

Comment: That likely would mean that there are 2 records in `STOCK_ACTIVITY` for which the `TYPE` really *is* `NULL`.  I guess I should've pointed out that if you use option 1, you need to distinguish a "real record with some `NULL` values" form a "generated `NULL` record".  In most sensible data models you can do that by checking if the right-table PK values are `NULL`; or certainly you could test if the right-table values for the join key are `NULL` (since an = join won't match such a record)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `STOCK_ACTIVITY` for a `CUSTOMER` a line full of `NULL`s will be attached. This also means that the `WHERE` statement `AND (S.TYPE = 'RECEIPT' OR S.TYPE = 'INVOICE')` never can be true for those lines.

Answer (score -1):

Keep the aggregate operation separated from the JOIN. That is the cleanest. First do the grouping then join the additional information.

Comment: doesn't address the problem, and depending on the DBMS may be bad advice performance-wise

Comment: You're right but 500 lines are not siginificant for performance point of view a sparating information can help understand the logic - better learning curve than writing the solution. No offence.

Comment: Your opinion is noted, but this is a question-and-ANSWER site, not a question-and-tell-you-what-I-think-is-wrong-with-you-for-asking-it site.